# NotRetryableException after a RetryableException considered as RetryableException in Spring Kafka ErrorHandler?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm implementing a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a basic recoverer (just a log) and an infinite `ExponentialBackOff` when database is not here :

```java
@KafkaListener(
    containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
    topics = "myTopic",
    clientIdPrefix = "myClientPrefix"
)
public void onMessage(@Payload List<MyObject> data, Acknowledgment ack) {
    try {
        if (timer++ % 3 == 0) {
            throw new AnNotRetryableException("Error !!!");
        }
        // handleMyObjectData() can throw an Retryable Exception
        MyObjectService.handleMyObjectData(data);
        ack.acknowledge();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error Message", e);
        throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException("Error Message", e);
    }
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ?> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ?> factory = buildListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConcurrency(consumerConcurrency);
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(retryDatabaseConnectionErrorHandler());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(kafkaTopicTaskExecutor());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMicrometerEnabled(false);
    factory.setMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(new ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter()));
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public CommonErrorHandler retryDatabaseConnectionErrorHandler() {

   ExponentialBackOff exponentialBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff(backOffInitialValue.toMillis(), backOffMultiplier);
   exponentialBackOff.setMaxElapsedTime(Long.MAX_VALUE);
   exponentialBackOff.setMaxInterval(backOffMaxInterval.toMillis());

   LoggingConsumerRecordRecoverer loggingConsumerRecordRecoverer = new LoggingConsumerRecordRecoverer();

   DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(loggingConsumerRecordRecoverer, exponentialBackOff);
    errorHandler.setClassifications(Map.of(CannotCreateTransactionException.class, true), false);
}
```

We have a batch listener of 50 records each time, saving them on database on service layer.
Let say I'm adding a chaos `NotRetryableException` in my listener, 1 out of 3 pollings, this `NotRetryableException` is thrown.

I start my consumption and I stop my database. `CannotCreateTransactionException` is thrown, and my batch is retried after an interval. Second time, same thing, the batch is retried after an interval. Third time, my `NotRetryableException` is thrown, but my batch is still retried... I expected here the batch goes to `LoggingConsumerRecordRecoverer`.

Note that if `NotRetryableException` is thrown right after stopping my database (I have a break point in debug mode, stopping the database and resuming the execution), the batch goes straight to `LoggingConsumerRecordRecoverer`.

Is it normal thing ? If my batch really has a `NotRetryableException` when database comes back, my retry becomes an infinite loop !

Using version of Spring Boot (2.7.8).

Answer (score 0):

This property is false on error handlers before version 2.9; set it to true, or upgrade to 2.9.x.

Boot 2.7.x pulls in version 2.8.x (which is no longer supported), use 2.9.x (2.9.6 is the current version) with Boot 2.7.x.

```java
/**
 * Set to true to reset the retry {@link BackOff} if the exception is a different type
 * to the previous failure for the same record. The
 * {@link #setBackOffFunction(BiFunction) backOffFunction}, if provided, will be
 * called to get the {@link BackOff} to use for the new exception; otherwise, the
 * configured {@link BackOff} will be used. Default true since 2.9; set to false
 * to use the existing retry state, even when exceptions change.
 * @param resetStateOnExceptionChange true to reset.
 * @since 2.6.3
 */
public void setResetStateOnExceptionChange(boolean resetStateOnExceptionChange) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Idea was good I think, but it seems to not working properly. I added more context on my question. On debug, it does not go to the place where  `resetStateOnExceptionChange` is used.

Please not we cannot say which record has a problem, because we handle our payload as an entire list, not one by one.

Comment: Oh; right; that will only work with a  record listener; please open an issue on GitHub to support exception type changes for a batch listener, and I'll take a look.

Comment: I went ahead and created an issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2620

Comment: Thank you Gary, I was busy at office yesterday. Looking forward to get this functionality

Comment: It should be released next Monday; a snapshot should be available soon (after the PR is reviewed/merged).

Comment: I will take that into account after our Spring Boot 3 migration, thank you !!

Comment: It is also fixed in 2.9.7 which is compatible with Boot 2.7.x.